# overwrite type definition of npm package

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, typescript-typings

I use the direct-vuex package with vuexfire. Now I need to change some type defs from the direct-vuex package for compatibility with vuexfire.

How can I do that?

It have no effect when I declare the direct-vuex module in my types file. My other type defs working fine.

```
declare module 'direct-vuex' {

  export type ToDirectStore<O extends AppStore> = ShowContent<{
    readonly state: ShowContent<DirectState<O>>
    getters: ShowContent<DirectGetters<O>>
    commit: ShowContent<DirectMutations<O>>
    dispatch: ShowContent<DirectActions<O>>
    original: VuexStore<O>
  }>

  type DirectActions<O extends StoreOrModuleOptions> =
    ToDirectActions<OrEmpty<O['actions']>>
    & GetActionsInModules<FilterNamespaced<OrEmpty<O['modules']>>>
    & MergeActionsFromModules<FilterNotNamespaced<OrEmpty<O['modules']>>>

  type ToDirectActions<T extends ActionsImpl> = {
    [K in keyof T]: Parameters<T[K]>[1] extends undefined
      ? (() => PromiseOf<ReturnType<T[K]>>)
      : ((payload >>>>>> Here i need to add a "?" sign <<<<<<<<<: Parameters<T[K]>[1]) => PromiseOf<ReturnType<T[K]>>)
  }
}
```

Thanks for help